# Laravel timstamp set from Carbon::parse()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

I have a db column 'expired_at' which is migrated using $table->timestamp('expired_at')

My form input of date for is March 26, 2016

I am setting my db column value using

```
 [ ... 'expired_at' => Carbon::parse($inputs['expired_at'])->toDateTimeString(); ... ]
```

But it inserts timestamp in db 0000-00-00 00:00:00

How can I insert timestamp using Carbon::parse() ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. [I made this eval.in example](https://eval.in/561034) which illustrates that it works, when you're passing in a Date just like your code indicates. My thoughts are actually that your `$inputs['expired_at']` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some more description for your Question, as per understanding

It seems that you want current time stamp to store for `expired_at`. you can do it by this

```
'expired_at' => Carbon::now()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a protected `$dates` property to your model and Laravel will automatically convert that column to a Carbon instance upon inserting into the table. Please refer to [Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = ['expired_at'];
```